# NullPointer Exception in adding contact number

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-contacts

I want to iterate through contacts and then add new numbers to them. A Null Pointer Exception rises in ApplyBatch().

**This is my code for getting the iD**

```
 protected Object doInBackground(Object[] objects) {
    final String[] projection = new String[] {
            RawContacts.CONTACT_ID, // the contact id column
            RawContacts.DELETED     // column if this contact is deleted
    };
    final Cursor rawContacts = context.getContentResolver().query(
            RawContacts.CONTENT_URI,    // the URI for raw contact provider
            projection,
            null,                    // selection = null, retrieve all entries
            null,                    // selection is without parameters
            null);                  // do not order
    final int contactIdColumnIndex = rawContacts.getColumnIndex(RawContacts.CONTACT_ID);

    final int deletedColumnIndex = rawContacts.getColumnIndex(RawContacts.DELETED);

    if(rawContacts.moveToFirst()) {
        while(!rawContacts.isAfterLast()) {     // still a valid entry left?
            final int contactId = rawContacts.getInt(contactIdColumnIndex);
            final boolean deleted = (rawContacts.getInt(deletedColumnIndex) == 1);
            if(!deleted) {
                EditContactPhone(contactId);
            }
            rawContacts.moveToNext();           // move to the next entry
        }
    }
    rawContacts.close();
    if (!ops.isEmpty()) {
        try {
            context.getContentResolver().applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, ops);
        } catch (RemoteException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (OperationApplicationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

**This is the EditContactPhone Method Where it adds data into ops**

```
private void EditContactPhone(int contactId) {
    final String[] projection = new String[] {
            Phone.NUMBER,
            Phone.TYPE
    };
    final Cursor phone =  context.getContentResolver().query(
            Phone.CONTENT_URI,
            projection,
            Data.CONTACT_ID + "=?",
            new String[]{String.valueOf(contactId)},
            null);
    if(phone.moveToFirst()) {
        while (!phone.isAfterLast()) {
            String newNumber = buildNineFineNine(number); //Function which modify the NewNumber to be added
            ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(Data.CONTENT_URI)
                            .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID, contactId)
                            .withValue(Data.MIMETYPE, Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
                            .withValue(Phone.NUMBER, newNumber)
                            .withValue(Phone.TYPE, Phone.TYPE_CUSTOM)
                            .withValue(Phone.LABEL, "NineFiveNine")
                            .build());
                    phone.moveToNext();
        }
    }
    phone.close();
}
```

When I switch ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID to RAW_CONTACT_ID , it finishes successfully but numbers are added into wrong contacts. I still can't figure out why it's showing me nullPointer Exception.

This is LOGCAT

```
01-18 23:46:02.955  15824-15955/vapp.ninefivenineconverter E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
        at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:352)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:219)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:239)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:838)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1434)
        at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:185)
        at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionWithOperationApplicationExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:160)
        at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.applyBatch(ContentProviderNative.java:461)
        at android.content.ContentProviderClient.applyBatch(ContentProviderClient.java:225)
        at android.content.ContentResolver.applyBatch(ContentResolver.java:976)
        at vapp.ninefivenineconverter.ConverterTask.doInBackground(ConverterTask.java:67)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
```

Answer (score 0):

The first problem could be here:

```
 .withValue(Phone.NUMBER, newNumber)
```

Make sure that **newNumber** is not Null.

If that doesn't help and still the problem happens, try to use the URI:

```
ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTENT_URI);
```

instead of this

```
ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI);
```

Next thing that worked is to simply use Data.CONTENT_URI along with RAW_CONTACT_ID:

```
ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
                    .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, id)
                    .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
                    .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER, newNumber)
                    .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_CUSTOM)
                    .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.LABEL, "NineFiveNine").build());
```

Comment: I changed it as you said, AsyncTask Finishes but there was no changes in any of the contacts. Tried with both RAW_CONTACT_ID and CONTACT_ID.

Comment: So NullpointerException is no longer thrown after changing URI?

Comment: Yes there was no longer Null Pointer Exception

Comment: Please check the answer, hopefully it will help.

Comment: Sorry for the late Reply, My Internet has been down for a whole week. The converting task finishes with no errors but then the phone no are wrongly added. Here's the screenshot how it wrongly added no to wrong contacts => http://imgur.com/ZWsT9WD